# showing that a map is a quotient map under certain conditions

Tags: general-topology

Let f : L -> K be a surjective continuous map. If both L, K are compact and Hausdorff, could anyone tell me how to prove that f is a quotient map?

Comment: Do you remember a few sufficient criteria for a map to be a quotient map?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a quotient map if a set $A$ is closed in $Y$ iff $f^{-1}A$ is closed in $X$

Consider a closed set $A$ of $Y$ then $ f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$ by continuity of $f$.Again consider the closed set  $f^{-1}A$ in $X$ then since every closed subset of a compact space in $T_2$ space is compact so $f^{-1}A$   is compact.Continuous image of a compact set being compact $f(f^{-1}A)=A$(since $f$ is surjective) is compact.Every compact set in a $T_2$ space is closed and hence $A$ is closed in $Y$